# How to code this if else clause in R?

Tags: r

I have a function that outputs a list containing strings. Now, I want to check if this list contain strings which are all 0's or if there is at least one string which doesn't contain all 0's (can be more).
I have a large dataset. I am going to execute my function on each of the rows of the dataset. Now,

Basically,

```
for each row of the dataset
    mylst <- func(row[i])
    if (mylst(contains strings containing all 0's) 
        process the next row of the dataset
    else 
        execute some other code
```

Now, I can code the if-else clause but I am not able to code the part where I have to check the list for all 0's. How can I do this in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `for` loop:

```
for (i in seq(nrow(dat))) {
    if( !any(grepl("^0+$", dat[i, ])) )
        execute some other code
}
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Here, the regex `"^0+$"` matches a string that consists of `0`s only.

Comment: I guess, I havent been able to explain correctly.  What I will do is apply the function on each row of the dataset and then check if the list contains all 0's or not.

Comment: @Qirohchan DP you want to execute the code if *all* elements consist of zeroes only?

Comment: I firstly run a code on the initial row of the dataset. Then depending upon the result, if the list consists of strings containing all 0's, then I will directly move on to the next row of the dataset. Otherwise, if the result doesnt contain all 0's, then, I would execute some other piece of code. Sorry for being unclear initially.

Comment: @Qirohchan  Can you provide a small reproducible example together with the expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest solution that avoids use of explicit for-loop. 
For a given data set `df`, one can find a logical vector that indicates the rows with all zeroes:

```
all.zeros <- apply(df,1,function(s) all(grepl('^0+$',s))) # grepl() was taken from the Sven's solution
```

With this logical vector, it is easy to subset `df` to remove all-zero rows:

```
df[!all.zeros,]
```

and use it for any subsequent transformations.

**'Toy' dataset**

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c('00','01','00'),V2=c('000','010','020'))
```

**UPDATE**

If you'd like to apply the function to each row first and then analyze the resulting strings, you should slightly modify the `all.zeros` expression:

```
all.zeros <- apply(df,1,function(s) all(grepl('^0+$',func(s))))
```